# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить запятые в данном предложении:
"Первый (?) правильно ответивший (?) получит приз".

Answer (score 3):

**Запятые здесь не нужны**, так как "первый правильно ответивший" - это подлежащее.  Внутри подлежащего знаки не ставим.

Comment: А разве не первый  подлежащее, а  правильно ответивший - причастный оборот?

Comment: Конечно, "правильно ответивший" - это причастный оборот. Но в данном предложении он становится частью подлежащего. Более того, причастие "ответивший" здесь употребляется в роли существительного: КТО? ответивший. А ПЕРВЫЙ зависит от ОТВЕТИВШИЙ.

Comment: И что? Наречие зависит от существительного? Так бывает?

Comment: Бывает. Дом напротив. Яйцо всмятку.

Answer (score 2):

А  может,  причастный оборот относится к пропущенному подлежащему 'человек' и выделяется запятыми?

Comment: Но в таком случае это будет совершенно другое по структуре предложение: Первый человек, правильно ответивший, ... Здесь уже подлежащее [ПЕРВЫЙ] ЧЕЛОВЕК, а ПРАВИЛЬНО ОТВЕТИВШИЙ - определение, выраженное причастным оборотом. Это определение относится к слову ЧЕЛОВЕК.

Comment: Значит, предложение по-разному понять. И знаки по-разному.

Answer (score 0):

где в данном случае нужны запятые? 
**Также(?) при покупке в сети "Золотое яблоко" можно получить подвеску в подарок в нашем ювелирном торговом центре "Голден парк"(?) по адресу Щорса, 29!**

На мой взгляд, само  предложение коряво построено.

Я попросила расставить запятые в тексте, который выделен жирным шрифтом. А не во всем тексте))